# NHibernate How to update Id on IEntity

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a row in my DB w/ Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',

how can I  force update this Id using session/transaction ,basically assign a valid Id to the row.

I've tried:

```
var testrow  = repo.get(id);
testrow.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
repo.UpdateRow(testRow);
```

---

My update repository update method:

```
public void UpdateRow(TestRow row)
        {
            using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Update(row);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

---

I get the error:

```
"Row was updated or deleted by another transaction"
```

If I attempt to delete the object using :

```
session.delete(row) 
transaction.Commit();
```

I get the following error:

```
Unexpected row count: 3; expected: 1
```

---

There are 3 rows each with a unique Id, one happens to have an incorrect Id of 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not 1 row with that id - but three. Try using a DB-tool and do a regular `select * from [table] where id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'` - I'll bet that is your problem. That would give the unexpected error - and for the love of all that is good - have a unique constraint on you id-column :-).

Also, your update method violates the unit of work pattern that is ISession. You load the object in one session, update it - and then try to make the update in another session - that is bound to give you unexpected results!

Always make this kind of work in *one* ISession!

EDIT: By the way - nHibernate cannot update your Id - that is how nHibernate knows which object you are holding! It simply doesn't make sense what you are doing. If you really need to update that row - use a DB-tool and do it manually (and take measures so it cannot happen again...)

EDIT2: To correct the problem, use this in code: nHibernate supports raw sql - use ISession.CreateSQLQuery("DELETE FROM [table] WHERE Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'").ExecuteUpdate();

Comment: It does have a unique constraint on Id, there are 3 rows but only one with 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.

Comment: Hmm... it might be nHibernate throwing a weird error because you are trying to do things, that is against the whole idea of nHibernate... I'd still go with a DB-tool to fix it - I take it, it wasn't supposed to happen, right?

Comment: No it wasn't, NHibernate is a but picky sometimes

Comment: You have a saved entity that looks unsaved to nHibernate (ie. the '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' id) - dragons are afoot when that happens...

Comment: Is there a way to remove the entity from within the code, instead of having to do it manually in the db?

Comment: nHibernate supports raw sql - use ISession.CreateSQLQuery("DELETE FROM [table] WHERE Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'").ExecuteUpdate();

Comment: yeah I was thinking SqlCommand but your suggestion is better. Edit this into you answer and I will accept it. Thanks Mate.

Answer (score 5):

An id must never change, this an error in your application design. Delete the old entity and recreate with the new values.

Comment: Is this the only option? If I attempt to delete it via code session.delete(row) I get the error: Unexpected row count: 3; expected: 1

Comment: By definition and id never change. An id must be unique an immutable. Verify there isn't duplicated objects in your db.

Comment: All the Ids are unique, one just happens to be 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 which is the one causing the issue.